# What type of application is a server side application?

Tags: .net, iis-7.5

This is a bit of a strange question.

I have a few friends and we all play halo, call of duty, forza when we have the time. To spice it up a bit we were talking about sticking IIS 7 on machine and writing an service that we could build a few applications on top of, mainly a web app and a mobile site that we could use to build a little fantasy league. Eventually we would like to extend this out onto mobile platforms if it works for us.

The problem is none of us have ever written any code server side. We are looking to build it in a disconnected approach. The server calls out to the DB, the web app calls out the the server and so on.

We understand the DB and web app side, but how do you write a server app? Is it just a console application ran as a service? Does it require any special design, does IIS handle concurrent users?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. We have been searching for the last few days regarding this but as the term server is ambiguous we are not getting great results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean a [windows service application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

You might also want to look at [Topshelf](http://code.google.com/p/topshelf/) to simplify creating a windows service.

(Note: the google code page seems to be unavailable currently - but there are lots of articles about Topshelf: e.g: [Create a .NET Windows Service in 5 steps with Topshelf](http://www.christophdebaene.com/blog/2011/03/16/create-a-net-windows-service-in-5-steps-with-topshelf/)).

Comment: Is this the sort of application that would normally be used to work on a server? Or are there varying types?

Comment: @deanvmc: If I understand your question correctly, then yes that's what you'd use on a server. A windows service can be started automatically (when windows starts) and does not require a user to log-in and start it. Also windows services do not have user interfaces (as they run in the background). Have a look at the first link - it gives an introduction to windows services.